# Powershell/Exchange Management Console

Tags: powershell, exchange-management-shell

I am attempting to, due to a user request, change the ExternalDsnMaxMessageAttachSize attribute from the exchange management shell. When I run the following command:

```
set-transportconfig -ExternalDsnMaxMessageAttachSize 20 MB
```

It works perfectly.

When I run the same command as an admin in powershell, it won't run, and ultimately no changes are made.

I am a powershell novice to say the least, but am I missing something here?

Is there a way I could push these changes out?

Comment: If you are running powershell/powershell ISE you have to tell it to connect to exchange first using `Import-PSSession`. What version of exchange are you running?

Comment: I did to connect in the firstplace. I just think this command doesn't work on with normal PS.